# What is the best Method for monitoring a large number of clients reliably with good performance

Tags: c#, performance, network-programming, monitoring

This is more of a programming strategy and direction question, than the actual code itself.

I am programming in C-Sharp.

I have an application that remotely starts processes on many different clients on the network, could be up to 1000 clients in theory.

It then monitors the status of the remote processes by reading a log file on each client.

I currently do this by running one thread that loops through all of the clients in a list, and reading the log file. It works fine for 10 or 20 machines, but 1000 would probably be untenable.

There are several problems with this approach:

First, if the thread doesn’t finish reading all of the client statuses before it’s called again, the client statuses at the end of the list might not be read and updated.

Secondly,  if any client in the list goes offline during this period, the updating hangs, until that client is back online again.

So I require a different approach, and have thought up a few possible ways to resolve this.

1. Spawn a separate thread for each client, to read their log file and update its progress.

   a.   However, I’m not sure if having 1000 threads running on my machine is something that would be acceptable.
2. Test the connect for each machine first, before trying to read the file, and if it cannot connect, then just ignore it for that iteration and move on to the next client in the list.

   a.   This still has the same problem of not getting through the list before the next call, and causes more delay and it tries to test the connection via a port first. With 1000 clients, this would be noticeable.
3. Have each client send the data to the machine running the application whenever there is an update.

   a.   This could create a lot of chatter with 1000 machines trying to send data repeatedly.

So I’m trying to figure if there is another more efficient and reliable method, that I haven’t considered, or which one of these would be the best.

Right now I’m leaning towards having the clients send updates to the application, instead of having the application pulling the data.

Looking for thoughts, concerns, ideas and recommendations.

Comment: .. use a database?

Comment: yeah, the easiest and most maintainable would to to setup a database and then have your machine trigger something on each of the clients. Then just check back as data flows into the database

Comment: Thanks for the downvotes for asking a question. For those who offered helpful advice, and aren't Premadonna's like some people here, thanks.

Answer (score 1):

In my opinion, you are doing this (Monitoring) the wrong way. Instead of keeping all logs in a text file, you'd better preserve them in a central data repository that can be of any kind. With respect to the fact that you are monitoring the performance of those system, your design and the mechanism behind it must not impact the performance of the target systems negatively, and with this design the disk and CPU would be involved so much in certain cases that can result in a performance issue itself.

I recommend you to create a log repository server using a fast in-memory database like Redis, and send logged data directly to that server. Keep in mind that this database must be running on a different virtual machine. You can then tune Redis to store received data on physical Disk once a particular number of indexes are reached or a particular interval elapses. The in-memory feature here is advantageous as you may need to query information a lot in a monitoring application like this. On the other hand, the performance of Redis is so high that it efficiently passes processing millions of indexes.

The blueprint for you is that:

1- Centralize all log data in a single repository.

2- Configure clients to send monitored information to the centralized repository.

3- Read the data from the centralized repository by the main server (monitoring system) when required.

I'm not trying to advertise for a particular tool here as I'm only sharing my own experience. There's many more tools that you can use for this purpose such as `ElasticSearch`.

Comment: Thanks. I guess I've been looking at this wrong. I've been in the mind set of a stand alone application, but I have design it more like an enterprise application.